# Storing the value of a form submission in a hidden field or the database

Tags: 7, database

So I have created a form for user's to store some documentation about a node they have created but I do not want this documentation to be shown on the node's main page.  I would like the main page to have a link to either view or edit the form.

Now as far as I can tell there is no way to create a field that doesn't show up directly on the node create or viewing pages (this seems like it would be a misuse of a field anyway).  Is there anyway that I could store what the user enters in this documentation form as part of the content without it being displayed on the node page or would I have to create a database table that associates a nid with the documentation string?  Also, my form allows for use of filtered html in the form, will this be preserved if I store the filtered html as a string in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a field not to show up on the node page you can either

1. hide it in display options: Structure -> Manage display (in front of the corresponding content type) -> Format -> Hidden
2. Hide it in the template file by calling

   ```
   hide($content['YOUR FIELD NAME']);
   ```

The first option makes more sense in my opinion.